# Can I make the following assumption about symmetric relations?

Tags: relations

If $R$ is a symmetric relation then:

$$(x,y) \not \in R \rightarrow (y,x) \not \in R$$

Comment: Yes. Perfectly legal. $\neg q\implies\neg p$ is the same statement as $p\implies q$. For $p$ you can take $(y,x)\in R$ and for $q$ you can take $(x,y)\in R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; the statements are equivalent.

Symmetry is the property that: $\forall x, y: \big((y,x)\in R\to (x,y)\in R\big)$

The contraposition of this is: $\forall x, y:\big( (x,y)\notin R\to (y,x)\notin R\big)$

Comment: Shouldn't the 'for all' be replaced by 'there exists'

Comment: No, @Shailesh.  If it is not "for all" then the relation *may* not be symmetric.  Symmetry is only assured if the implications hold for all pairs from the universe.  The existence of one example is not sufficient; there must be no contrary cases.

Comment: Additionally, contraposition is an equivalence, so no form of Dual Negation is applicable.  If $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$ are (syntactically) equivalent statements, then $\forall x,y : P(x,y)$ and $\forall x,y: Q(x,y)$ are equivalent statements, but $\exists x,y:Q(x,y)$ is not equivalent (it's weaker).